# Coloring in ComplexListPlot

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, complex

I want to plot the points of a complex sequence with colors changing from point to point. I tried

```
ComplexListPlot[
 Table[Labeled[1 - 1/(1 + I)^n, Subscript[z, n]], {n, 1, 15}], 
 AxesLabel -> {"Re(z)", "Im(z)"}, PlotRange -> All, 
 GridLines -> Automatic, 
 AxesStyle -> Directive[Black, Arrowheads[{0.0, 0.03}]], 
 PlotStyle -> ColorData["Rainbow"]]
```

I can't see a change in the color of the points. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to wrap each point in its own list.

```
ComplexListPlot[
 Table[{Labeled[1 - 1/(1 + I)^n, Subscript[z, n]]}, {n, 1, 15}], 
 AxesLabel -> {"Re(z)", "Im(z)"}, PlotRange -> All, 
 GridLines -> Automatic, 
 AxesStyle -> Directive[Black, Arrowheads[{0.0, 0.03}]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This will use the default list of discrete colors. To use a continuous color scheme (such as Rainbow), you have to sample it equidistantly. (There might be some other way which I am not familiar with.)

```
pts = Table[{Labeled[1 - 1/(1 + I)^n, Subscript[z, n]]}, {n, 1, 15}];
ComplexListPlot[pts, AxesLabel -> {"Re(z)", "Im(z)"}, 
 PlotRange -> All, GridLines -> Automatic, 
 AxesStyle -> Directive[Black, Arrowheads[{0.0, 0.03}]], 
 PlotStyle -> 
  Table[ColorData["Rainbow", i/(Length[pts] - 1)], {i, 0, 
    Length[pts] - 1}]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]